# GeoServer showing different style based on zoom

Tags: geoserver, style, sld, geoserver-styling

I have a .tiff file that I'm uploading to GeoServer. I'm able to create layer successfully, but when I'm viewing the data, it shows different colored image based on zoom (I have not configured style for it).

smaller zoom level
[image: smaller zoom level]

bigger zoom level
[image]

bigger zoom level ( where actually image stat appearing )
[image]

What might be the issue here ?

I do have .tif and .ers file present.

Also when I open same file in `QGIS` it works perfectly fine on all zoom levels

Comment: do you have any overviews set? which `Interpolation Method` did you pick?

Comment: `Interpolation Method` is the default one - `nearest neighbor`